# NullPointerException in Eclipse but not in command promt

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, command-prompt

I'm a beginner. Just wondering why this code works perfectly fine in windows command prompt, but I get an:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at Test1.main(Test1.java:13)
```

error in eclipse. This has happened a lot to me, and it's really stopping me from using eclipse.

Here's the code:

import java.io.Console;

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Console myConsole = System.console();

        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++){           
            int a2 = a * a;         
            myConsole.printf("\n%d squared is: %d.",a,a2); //Problem with this line
        }       
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, `System.console()` is returning `null` in Eclipse, but not when run in a console. This is the [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29) behaviour:

> Returns the unique Console object associated with the current Java virtual machine, if any.
>
> Returns:
> The system console, if any, otherwise null.

Why not just use `System.out` instead? After all, you don't *need* any of the functionality of `Console`.

Answer (score 4):

The javadoc for `System.console()` states

> **Returns** The system console, if any, otherwise null.

Eclipse must not associate a system console.

Use `System.in` instead, possibly with a `java.util.Scanner` for input. And `System.out` for output.

Comment: How exactly is System.in going to be useful when the OP is only using the console for *output*?

Answer (score 2):

[`System#console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29) may return `null` in certain environments. Since youre simply outputting to the console, you don't need to use `Console`. `Formatter` can be used instead:

```
System.out.printf("\n%d squared is: %d.", a, a2);
```